# using local variable value in SQL statement in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to subtract number of days from a date dynamically in sql atatement in

```
C# code I have is
int myInt=6;       //its value will vary
  var q = SELECT [DATE] FROM DB WHERE  [Date ] < DATEADD(dd, **myint**, GETDATE())";
```

is there way to pass this variable in sql statement ?

I tried this

```
 var q = SELECT [DATE] FROM DB WHERE  [Date ] < DATEADD(dd, [coumln]+"'+myint+'", GETDATE())";
```

Comment: Pass it in to where? C# code or SQL. You seem to have a SQL statement written where you have said C#

Comment: you are writing this query in C# or SQL Server?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: It would be a even better solution to do the date adding in C# and avoid SQL Server to run a add-function to all rows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes indeed, you should pass this as a parameter;

```
string connectionString = "YourConnectionString";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
                "SELECT [DATE] FROM DB WHERE [Date] < DATEADD(dd, @MyInt, GETDATE())", connection))
            {                    
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("MyInt", myInt));
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    DateTime date = reader.GetDateTime(0);
                    Console.WriteLine("Date: {0}",
                        date);
                }
            }
        }
```

You could also use something like LinqToSql: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx
Or an ORM like Dapper: https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper

Comment: can i do it without being  parameterized

Comment: Technically yes you can, but you really do not want to - it is worse in terms of performance, maintenance and security (SQL Injection attacks). Please use Parameters.... Why would you not want to use them?